# puppet apply sometimes fails with: Could not set 'directory on ensure: File exists - /var/lib/puppet/facts

Tags: puppet

We use "puppet apply" to setup newly created VM instances, but sometimes it fails with error below even though it passed X times before with the same instance and same manifest file:

```
err: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts]/ensure: change from absent to directory failed: Could not set 'directory on ensure: File exists - /var/lib/puppet/facts
Got 1 failure(s) while initializing: change from absent to directory failed: Could not set 'directory on ensure: File exists - /var/lib/puppet/facts
```

Since I haven't find anything about such error so I am asking here. Did somebody had this issue too already? What do you suggest as solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got the same problem.

A workaround is to write a script to run `puppet apply` command 5 times, which solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here was that there was zombie puppet process still running. After killing it this error never appeared again.